# Processes vs threads for gui program

Tags: multithreading, process

I was wondering, if you were to create seperate processes instead of seperate threads for any raised GUI events, should that, in theory, make the GUI more responsive?

If you try to raise a GUI event whilst another thread is executing, control might not switch straight away to the GUI thread, whereas if processes replaced threads, then there is no potential delay in handling a GUI event.

Comment: You certainly don't want to create a _new_ process or thread for each new event. That would be much less efficient than using a thread pool or, communicating with a long-running process.

Comment: Long ago, when thread packages were implemented mainly in user space, your thesis could have been true.   Now virtually all systems schedule threads-like entities directly in the kernel.   Even runtimes like GoLang uses many threads (but many more go-routines).  The key, like in any multi-threaded program is lock granularity.   If all the threads immediately compete for one big lock, then it isn't really multi-threaded and won't be responsive.